# Case-sensitivity with dplyr + RPostgreSQL string matching

Tags: r, dplyr, rpostgresql

I can't figure out how to apply a non-case-sensitive filter query to a remote PostgreSQL table using `dplyr`.  To demonstrate:

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
require(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="mydb", host="localhost", port=5432, user="username")

# create db table
copy_to(con, iris, "iris", temporary = FALSE)

# dplyr remote database table
iris_pg <- tbl(con, "iris")

iris_pg %>% filter(str_detect(Species, 'setosa')) %>% head(3) %>% collect()
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
*        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa

iris_pg %>% filter(str_detect(Species, 'Setosa')) %>% head(3) %>% collect()
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

To ignore case `stringr::fixed('Setosa', ignore_case=TRUE)` works with tibble filtering. But with the postgres table it has no effect:

```
iris_pg %>% filter(str_detect(Species, stringr::fixed('SETOSA', ignore_case=TRUE))) %>% head(3) %>% collect()
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because as you can see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/79d2a0377561ad57f67a65b914ce3195d10de0be/R/db-postgres.r#L68), when using a PostgreSQL backend, `dbplyr` relies on the case-sensitive function `STRPOS` to translate `str_detect` into SQL.

Some possible workarounds:

1) `filter(str_detect(tolower(myvar), tolower(pattern)))` probably works with any relational database.

2) `filter(myvar %~*% pattern)` relies on `~*`, the PostgreSQL operator for case-insensitive POSIX regexes.

3) `filter(myvar %ilike% paste0("%", pattern, "%"))` relies on `ILIKE`, a case-insensitive and Postgres-specific version of the standard `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Thanks Scarabee, this works ok. I wonder about the computational burden, but separate issue.